# Angular project getting an AbstractControl error on build

Tags: angular

I have some code that is erroring on build

ERROR in src\app\components\search.component.html(105,62): : Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

search.component.html(105,62):

```
<div class="col-xs-3 checkbox" formArrayName="events" *ngFor="let event of form.controls.events.controls; let i = index">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
          {{events[i]}}
    </label>
    <br *ngIf="i%4 === 3"/>
</div>
```

search.component.ts(portion dealing with events):

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this.eventsList = [
    ['item 1 A','item 2 A'],
    ['item 1 B','item 2 B'],
    ['item 1 C','item 2 C']
    ];

    this.events = [].concat.apply([], this.eventsList);

    this.form = new FormGroup({
    type: new FormControl(),
    state: new FormControl(),
    events: this.buildEventsForm()
    });
}



buildEventsForm() {
    let formControlArr = this.events.map((e: any) => {
    return new FormControl(false);
    });
    return new FormArray(formControlArr);
}
```

any help greatly appreciated.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ig3pau

Comment: Could you add a link to the stackblitz of the source code, not just the executed web site?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ig3pau 
Sorry - still unfamiliar with stackblitz...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this part:

```
form.controls.events.controls
```

To

```
form.controls.events.['controls']
```

In

```
<div class="col-xs-3 checkbox" formArrayName="events" *ngFor="let event of form.controls.events.controls; let i = index">
```

Will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

My prior answer was not entirely accurate. I just looked at one of mine and it looks like this:

```
  <div formArrayName="tags">
    <div *ngFor="let tag of tags.controls; let i=index">
      <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label"
             [attr.for]="i">Tag</label>

        <input class="form-control"
               [id]="i"
               type="text"
               [formControlName]="i" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Notice that is *is* accessing the `controls` property of the `tags` form array.

The component code looks like this:

```
  // Provides the FormArray accessed in the *ngFor
  get tags(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.productForm.get('tags');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productForm = this.fb.group({
      productName: ['', Validators.required,
      tags: this.fb.array([]),
      description: ''
    });
  }
```

Which is quite similar to yours.

If you add logging to this, do you see the correct info?

```
buildEventsForm() {

        let formControlArr = this.events.map((e: any) => {
        return new FormControl(false);
        });
        const newFormArray = new FormArray(formControlArr);
        console.log(newFormArray);
        return newFormArray;
    }
```

If you could provide a stackblitz of your scenario, we may be able to better determine what may be wrong.

**UPDATE**

I downloaded your your code from your stackblitz so I could run it with the `ng serve --prod` option and got the same error you reported.

I was able to fix it by bringing it closer to the original version of my code I posted above.

Using just:

```
form.controls.events.controls
```

in your HTML does not appropriate coerce the value to the correct type. In my code above, notice the `tags` getter. This *does* correctly coerce the data type.

So in your code, you need to add this to your component:

```
  get eventFormArray() {
    return <FormArray>this.form.get('events');
  }
```

The `<FormArray>` coerces the value to the correct data type.

Then in your html you use this getter in your `ngFor`:

```
*ngFor="let event of eventFormArray.controls; let i = index"
```

Let me know if that does not work for you.

Comment: events is an array of checkboxes. you are correct.
Your suggestion did get rid of the error, but I do not get the checkboxes now.
Where before - ng serve - would not error and Id get the checkboxes...but could not build or serve with --prod.

Comment: To really help you ... consider building a simple stackblitz to demonstrate what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thx Deborah...link above.

Comment: I downloaded your stackblitz so I could use `ng serve --prod` on it and found the issue. See my updated answer.